# If $E$ is finite, show that $E=F(u)$ for some $u\in E$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $E\supseteq F$ be fields. If $E$ is finite, show that $E=F(u)$ for some $u\in E$.

What I've come up with so far:

Let $u\in E$ be the primitive element of $E$. Then $E^*=\langle u \rangle$. So $E=\{0\}\cup \langle u \rangle$.

I want to jump right to $E=F(u)$, but I see it is clear that $E\supseteq F(u)$, but does this justify $E\subseteq F(u)$?

Comment: By your work, it seems that $E$ is a finite field, not just a finite extension? Since $u\in F(u)$, so is any power of $u$. Thus $E^\ast=\langle u\rangle\subset F(u)$. Since $0\in F(u)$, $E\subset F(u)$.

Comment: Yes, E is a finite field. That makes absolute sense thank you.